# What engine burn/thrust could be used for satellite longitudinal change?

Tags: orbital-maneuver

If you wish to change the longitude (but not the inclination) of a satellite in Low Earth Orbit, what kind of maneuvers could you use?

I am no expert, but let's say ISS or Hubble would like to stop "natural" nodal precession for a while, what could they do?

Starlink are spread by altitude differences in "natural" nodal precession. Let's say you wanted to speed this up by engine burns. How would you apply the burns to spread the nodes of the orbits without changing the inclination?

Comment: The little I have found out is naturally that you can give a  big burn where the orbits intersect. But this would for ex. not be possible with low thrust engines like Starlink krypton engines. // A wild guess, from just looking at a gyroscope, would be that a constant force, parallel to the ground, perpendicular to the orbit,  could induce precession?